# Highchart is not updating after setState (bubble motion)

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a service call on componentDidMount. Up on getting the data, I am trying to set my state which holds highchart information.

Code is below.

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
 // Import Highcharts
 import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
 import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
 import plugin from "../../../../resources/js/motion";

 import * as Services from '../../services/dashboardservices';
 import ProcessData from './bubbleChartMethods';

  require("highcharts/modules/map")(Highcharts);

  class LineContainer extends Component {

  style = {
    fontFamily: "'univers', Arial, sans-serif",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#333333"
  };

state = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            height: 380,
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy',
            resetZoomButton: {
                theme: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fill: '#D98C14',
                            stroke: '#BF7400',
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: "",

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Peak Load (A)',
                style: this.style
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: this.style
            },
            min: 0,
            maxPadding: 0.05,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#000',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    style: this.style,
                    text: 'Peak Load Threshold',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                },
                zIndex: 3,
                value: 30
            }],
            softMax: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Peak Unbalance (A)',
                style: this.style
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: this.style
            },
            min: 0,
            maxPadding: 0.1,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#000',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    align: 'center',
                    style: this.style,
                    text: 'Peak Unbalance Threshold'
                },
                zIndex: 3,
                value: 4
            }],
            softMax: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 2,
            headerFormat: '<div class="padding-0-10 padding-b-10"><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td colspan="2"><h5><strong>{point.name}</strong></h5></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">Peak Load: </td><td>{point.x} A</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">Peak Unbalance: </td><td>{point.y} A</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">Device Count: </td><td>{point.z}</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table></div>'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            bubble: {
                minSize: 20
            },
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '..',
                    style: { fontSize: 10, color: 'rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)', textOutline: false, fillOpacity: 0.1 },
                    color: 'rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)'
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            // $rootScope.$broadcast('loadHierarchy', { chartType: 'loadUnbalance', name: this.name });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        motion: {
            enabled: true,
            axisLabel: 'year',
            loop: false,
            series: 0, // The series which holds points to update
            updateInterval: 100,
            magnet: {
                round: 'round', // ceil / floor / round
                step: 0.1
            },
            labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            id: 'deep',
            marker: {
                fillColor: {
                    radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
                    ]
                }
            },
            data: []
        }]
    }
}
// Render app with demo chart

componentDidMount() {
    Services.getLoadAndUnbalanceData().then(res => {
        const renderObj = ProcessData(res);
        this.setState({
            options: {
                ...this.state.options,
                motion: {
                    ...this.state.options.motion,
                    labels: renderObj.timestamp
                },
                series: [{
                    ...this.state.options.series[0],
                    data: renderObj.series
                }],

                xAxis: {
                    ...this.state.options.xAxis,
                    softMax: renderObj.xSoftMax,
                    plotLines: [
                        {
                            ...this.state.options.xAxis.plotLines[0],
                            value: renderObj.maxLoadThreshold,
                            label: {
                                ...this.state.options.xAxis.plotLines[0].label,
                                text: renderObj.xLabelText
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    ...this.state.options.yAxis,
                    softMax: renderObj.ySoftMax,
                    plotLines: [
                        {
                            ...this.state.options.yAxis.plotLines[0],
                            value: renderObj.maxUnbalanceThreshold,
                            label: {
                                ...this.state.options.yAxis.plotLines[0].label,
                                text: renderObj.yLabelText
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={this.state.options}
        />
     );
   }
 }
```

Here I am able to get the render on set state. But data is not updating on chart. Am I setting it wrongly or what. Please suggest. If I debug I can able to see the changed data on render method. But highchart is not updating

Data I am getting like below

```
 [{"sequence":[{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":37.83,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":37.5,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":38.08,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":36.92,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":36,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13.08,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":14,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13.09,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":13,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"},{"color":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","fillColor":"rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)","x":0,"y":0,"z":3,"name":"California"}]}]
```

If I use normal data just like below it will work

```
[[2, 2], [10, 10]]
```

But it wont work sequence of data which motion video needs

Comment: Hello raj m, In your code I do not see the import of `highcharts-more` module. Also, I created a live example showing a similar situation to yours and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/50p5l109nn

Comment: Yes if we are giving plain data it will work. My case there is motion video which will get data like above. Please find edited page above

Comment: Hi raj m, Please see this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6voj2v88qr I am able to update the chart with your data. You need to have `series.data` format the same as required by Highcharts: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.data

Comment: You correct it may work. But bubble chart motion video need a sequence object in data. So that it can take video  @ppotaczek

Comment: @ppotaczek I have updated motion labels. Please refer. there are 15 sequences for 15 labels. Its not working with motion video

Comment: @ppotaczek I can say its problem with sequence object what bubble motion is needed inside data. If I put data directly to chart then motion will work. But not with setState. Even I tried rendering the chart. Still the same

Comment: thanks for clarifications. It looks like the motion plugin does not support `chart.update` and other similar methods. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6voj2v88qr - the plugin works with static data in your format.

Comment: Here are two examples, which shows the problem with `update`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pc1bkurd/ and http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xhcnrz69/

Comment: @ppotaczek So do you have any solution with dynamic data.

Comment: Hi raj m, Sorry but I do not have. Other methods like `setData` or `series.update` also do not work. I think that you should contact directly with the autor of the plugin: https://github.com/larsac07/Motion-Highcharts-Plugin/issues

Comment: I have posted questions. And please let me know if you have come across any solution